# automatically update buffers when focusing if file changed

Tags: auto-revert-mode, buffer-modified

When programming, I often switch from emacs to Xcode and viceversa.
When I switch to Xcode, it automatically updates the current file **when I focus Xcode window**, if it detects that there are some external changes.

In emacs I have to press C-x C-v (but I lose the cursor position) or I have to press something and then insert r (reload?) in the minibuffer when emacs asks me what to do.

How to make emacs automatically reload the file (without losing the cursor position), it when I select back a buffer it corresponds to a modified file?

Thank you.

Comment: After 24.4, there are focus hooks. See for example: http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/03/22/a-peek-at-emacs-24-dot-4-focus-hooks/

Answer (score 11):

This isn't specific to focus in/out but rather to just updating buffers when the underlying file changes.  Emacs calls this "reverting" the buffer and has the functions `revert-buffer` to do it manually and `auto-revert-mode` to revert automatically when the file changes on disk.  `auto-revert-mode` can be added to the hook for whatever mode your using or you turn on `global-auto-revert-mode` (by adding `(global-auto-revert-mode)` to your `.emacs`).